# SQL- Join on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 SQL tables: modems,ModemsImage and ModemsPckg

```
    +----+-------+----------+
    | MID| Name  | Desc     |
    +----+-------+----------+
    | 1  |RNO-505|Wifi Modem|
    +-----------------------+

    +--- -+----+---------+
    | MIID| MID| ICON    |
    +-- --+----+---------+
    | 1   |1   |Cloud.png|
    +-- --+----+---------+
    | 2   |1   |Wire.png |
    +--------------------+

    +-----+--------+------------+-----+---+
    |MPKID|PckgName|PDesc       |Price|MID|
    +-----+--------+------------+-----+---+
    |1    |basic   |Starter Pckg|20.5 |1  |
    +-----+--------+------------+-----+---+
    |2    |Enhanced|advance pckg|66.5 |1  |
    +-------------------------------------+
```

End result i want:

```
    +----+-------+----------+-----+---------+-----+--------+------------+-----+
    | MID| Name  | Desc     | MIID| ICON    |MPKID|PckgName|PDesc       |Price|
    +-----------------------+-----+---------+-----+--------+------------+-----+
    | 1  |RNO-505|Wifi Modem| 1   |Cloud.png|1    |basic   |Starter Pckg|20.5 | 
    +-----------------------+-----+---------+-----+--------+------------+-----+
    | 1  |RNO-505|Wifi Modem| 2   |Wire.png |2    |Enhanced|advance pckg|66.5 | 
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using this query:

```
select * from modems a join ModemsImage b on a.mid=b.mid join ModemsPckg c on a.mid=c.mid
```

but this will not give me correct output, its returning duplicate records just MPKID is different.
Thanks
**EDIT::** when i use, this query it show me perfect 2 records

```
    select c.MPKID from modems a join ModemsImage b on a.mid=b.mid join ModemsPckg c on a.mid=c.mid group by c.MPKID
```

but as soon as i tried to retrieve more columns it start to duplicate rows.

Comment: You got 4 rows, didn't you?

Comment: Yes i got 4 rows, but i want 2 rows only.

Comment: use join  as  'modem a join ModemsImage b on a.mid=b.mid join ModemsPckg c on b.mid=c.mid and b.MPKID=c.MPKID'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need add an additional criteria on ModemsImage and ModemsPckg.
For example:

```
select * from modems a 
INNER JOIN ModemsImage b on a.mid=b.mid 
INNER JOIN ModemsPckg c on a.mid=c.mid AND b.MIID=c.MPKID
```

Comment: How have you decided that b.MIID=c.MPKID?

Comment: Actually , I am not sure too, I guessed per the sample data, there are no other column can be link key, I guessed the sample is descripting the mode has two package, Every package has single image. As my understand, if the image of package is change, it can be treat as different package. But I am sure whether it is the actua l business of Belle, only give some tip

Comment: I am sure there is not relation between those 2 columns . MIID is a shortcut for ModemsImage ID and MPKID is a shortcut to ModemsPckg ID.

Answer (score 0):

- Modems      have 1 row  where MID = 1.
- ModemsImage have 2 rows where MID = 1.
- ModemsPckg  have 2 rows where MID = 1.

You are connecting them all by MID so you are getting:

- Modems 1st row + ModemsImage 1st row + ModemsPckghave 1st row
- Modems 1st row + ModemsImage 1st row + ModemsPckghave 2nd row
- Modems 1st row + ModemsImage 2nd row + ModemsPckghave 1st row
- Modems 1st row + ModemsImage 2nd row + ModemsPckghave 2nd row

Why would you expect anything else?

Comment: my query is wrong, i don't want to get repeated records.

Comment: So you have to find out how these tables relate to each other. Maybe there is an additional table that connects them?

Comment: i created these tables, i have to build logic. i failed, so i asked for help.

Comment: I don't know the relation between ModemsImage and ModemsPckg. You should probably do **one** of the following: (1) Add MIID to ModemsPckg (2) Add MPKID to ModemsImage (3) Create an additional table that has both MIID and MPKID